# Memory not clearing when exiting app

Tags: android, memory, ondestroy

I have looked through a few articles around and notice that sometimes onDestroy() is not called when an app is exiting. Sometimes only the onPause() is called. My whole thing is that when I exit my app with the back button OR the finish() function, everything looks fine. When I attempt to reopen my app, it says:

```
12-14 04:09:59.457: E/GraphicsJNI(996): VM won't let us allocate 3279360 bytes
```

I will paste the entire log as well. The thing is when it reopens, it force closes. After that, I can reopen it again. For example, whenever I rebuild it in Eclipse and run it through the emulator, it works fine. But if I close it inside the app and try to reopen it, that is when I get this memory issue. I am not sure what is not being cleared out and I really hope one of you guys has a solution or at least can point me in the right direction to resolve this because it is really giving me a headache. If you guys need more info, please let me know. Thanks.

```
12-14 04:09:59.457: E/GraphicsJNI(996): VM won't let us allocate 3279360 bytes
12-14 04:09:59.606: D/AndroidRuntime(996): Shutting down VM
12-14 04:09:59.646: W/dalvikvm(996): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ShotSlot/com.ShotSlot.ShotSlotActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.ShotSlot.ShotSlotActivity.onCreate(ShotSlotActivity.java:161)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  ... 11 more
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:170)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  ... 21 more
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
12-14 04:09:59.856: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  ... 25 more
```

Comment: I am not sure about inflate exception but OutOfMemoryError exception related to bitmap may because of you are using bitmap are trying to scale bitmap time fewer time. Try to reuse bitmap object and avoid scaling of bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in DDMS, it has a Heap tab that tells you the memory allocation.

Window > Open Perspective > Other...

Then choose DDMS

EDIT

In one of my apps, i have this set in a Quit button, it clears the backstack and starts the first activity in your app, just replace Main.class with your first activitys name. Then once you hit the back button the app exits

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I notice that when I am running the app, it is about 80% mem usage or so leaving about 750kb of free memory. When I close it, nothing changes, even running the garbage collector through DDMS. When I reopen it, I get the out of memory error. After that, the heap clears out in DDMS and I can reopen it again with no problem. I'm not sure how I can export the heap logs or anything. If I am able to, I will be glad to post them. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: is there a memory spike at the start of the activity? Like loading extra data, or something like that? That may push you over the top.

Comment: I don't any real spikes. Some small fluctuations, but nothing crazy. The main thing I notice though is that when I close out, everything stays in memory as if I didn't even close it. So basically, when I open the app the second time, all that memory is still allocated which doesn't make any sense to me. A lot of articles I read say that you don't need to worry about memory when the app closes because it takes care of itself, but I am not experiencing obviously. Also, I want to reiterate that after it force closes because of the memory error, I can open the app normally.

Comment: It stays in memory until android needs the memory, or it's killed by a taskmanager (I have my phone set to kill 90% of the apps after 2 minutes onPause lol). Did you leave any threads running? You can always empty the backstack before closing, I'll edit my post above and add some code.

Comment: If you can give me an example of clearing the back stack before close, then I think that will probably fix it. The issue I am seeing is that using the back button and the exit button that calls finish() are both causing this issue. How would I clear out any threads? My app is fairly heavily threaded, so maybe that is causing the problem. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I edited my post above with the code, and call finish() in the thread when done, or thread.finish() when exiting

Comment: None of this has helped any unfortunately. I am still pretty stuck with same memory issue.